# New to mongoose, Schema dbref using string type but populate method does not work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am relatively new to mongoose and mongo. I am designing two schemas *btw, i am using nodeJS*

**Device**

```
var deviceSchema = new Schema({
    device_id : {type: String}
    , name : {type: String, default: null}
    , code : {type: String, default: null}
    , status : {type: String, default: null}
    , type : {type: String, default: null}
    , type2 : {type: String, default: null}
    , description : {type: String, default: null}
    , deployment_date : {type: Date, default: null}
    , create_date : {type: Date, default: null}
    , last_update : {type: Date, default: null}
    , entity_id : {type: String, ref: 'entity'}
    , enterprise_id : {type: String, ref: 'enterprise'}
});
```

**Device Relationship**

```
var deviceRelationshipSchema = new Schema({
    device_relationship_id : {type: String}
    , device_id : {type: String, ref: 'device'}
    , entity_id : {type: String, ref: 'entity'}
    , last_update : {type: Date, default: null}
    , create_date : {type: Date, default: null}
    , app_name : {type: String, default: null}
    , authorize : {type: String, default: null}
});
```

I am trying to do a call that will nest device object into device relationship using moongoose populate functionality as seen in this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5e1NEdfs4is

**This is the method**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.model('device_relationship').find({}, function(err, deviceRelationship){
        mongoose.model('device_relationship').populate(deviceRelationship, { path : 'device' }, function (err, deviceRelationship){
            res.json(deviceRelationship);
        })
    });
```

BUT, my result still does not have the device object nested in it

**Result**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "54d3248516d64ae206752a75",
    "device_relationship_id": "VZ25VRVA-3FOIA8RM-N5ABI98A",
    "device_id": "z0a783118008",
    "__v": 0,
    "authorize": null,
    "app_name": null,
    "create_date": "2014-05-01T10:00:00.000Z",
    "last_update": "2015-02-05T08:06:29.000Z"
  },

...
]
```

Please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try find with exec.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var device_relationship = mongoose.model('device_relationship');
device_relationship.find({}).populate('device').exec(function(err, deviceRelationship){
    res.json(deviceRelationship);
});
```